# Docker restarting specific service of multiple docker-compose process tags

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have multiple sets two of Docker services running simultaneously, so my `docker ps` logs look something like this:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
0a8e26682915   image_name:latest   "bash -c 'pip instal…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                                   process_name_1_actions_1
ed8b56ff29b1   image_name:latest   "bash -c 'cd live-bo…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, :::5005->5005/tcp       process_name_1_model_1
6d8016412d12   image_name:latest   "bash -c 'pip instal…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                                   process_name_2_actions_1
128d3605297a   image_name:latest   "bash -c 'cd live-bo…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5006->5005/tcp, :::5006->5005/tcp       process_name_2_model_1
```

Note that the names of these services have tags. I would like to create a shell script which can loop through these sets of processes by their tags, and restart the `actions_1` service. Something like:

```bash
declare -a arr=("process_1" "process_2")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    # here, restart only the 'actions_1' service of process i.
done
```

Justification for this is that the processes titled `_model_1` takes a long time to spawn. The process titled `_actions_1` needs to be restarted often, and does not take a long time to spawn. For this reason, running `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up` is a very tedious process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command

`docker ps --format '{{.Names}} {{.ID}}' | awk '{if ($1 ~ "_actions_1") print $2;}' | xargs -P 10 docker restart`

Description ::

`docker ps --format '{{.Names}} {{.ID}}`: Lists current containers running with only 2 fields - name & id

`awk`: Checks $1 i.e. image name via regex, if matches, then prints corresponding $2 i.e. container id

`xargs` Executes specified command one by one upon the output. `-P 10` executes 10 restarts in parallel at most, to speed things up.

Comment: Hi, what part of this filters the container IDs by `_actions_1`? This would restart 10 containers, some of which might be the `_model_1` containers, no?

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions to restart individual services by their docker-compose tag? Your solution did not work

Comment: Hi @SteinnHauserMagnusson , oops, my bad, I misinterpreted. I have updated the answer, it should work :)

Comment: Thank-you! This solution works very nicely @iArc13